# Differentiating a trig series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

The following two sentences are from the 7th edition of  book "Calculus and Analytic Geometry" by
George B. Thomas and Ross L Finney:

For example, a theorem that is valid for power series says, in effect, that the derivative of a power series $\sum a_n x^n$ is $\sum n a_n x^{n-1}$. However, it is not true that the derivative of the trigonometric series $ \sum \left( 1/n \right) \sin nx$ is $\sum \cos nx$.

It seems to me the second statement is true assuming you have appropriate limits. That is, the book's statement is some where between poorly worded and wrong. The issue is the book did not provide any limits on the summation. Please consider the following series:
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left( 1/n \right) \sin nx $$
I claim that
$$ f'(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}  \cos nx $$
which is not much different from the author's second statement which he claimed was wrong.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\cos nx$ is divergent (unless understood in a very specific sense, e.g. distributional - which is *not* the case, given the context).

Comment: "...that the derivative of a power series $\sum a_n x^n$ is $\sum na_nx^{n−1}$" : this is not true in general, this theorem has important hypothesis.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe is the problem differentiating $\sum a_n x^n$ that the series is not convergent for all $x$?

Comment: @Bob To differentiate a series of functions term by term, you must ask for the uniform convergence of the series of the derivatives.